# I can't understand why this openmp program doesn't scale well

Tags: c, openmp

I've just recently started using openmp and can't understand why this program isn't scaling well:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define THREAD_NUMBER 4

int main() {
    double start, end;

    double pi = 0.0;;
    int actual_threads;
    unsigned long numSteps = 1000000000;
    double stepSize = 1.0/numSteps;
    
    omp_set_num_threads(THREAD_NUMBER);
    start = omp_get_wtime();

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction (+:pi)
        for (int i = 0; i < numSteps; i++) {
            pi += 4.0/(1 + (0.5 + i)*stepSize*(0.5 + i)*stepSize);
        }
    pi *= stepSize;

    end = omp_get_wtime();
    printf("runtime: %.10fs\n", end - start);
    printf("pi = %.15f\n", pi);

    return 0;
}
```

It's just a basic test program in C for me to get used to the openmp directives. When I run it with 1 thread it gives me about 3.5 seconds of runtime in the parallel section only. But when I run it with 4 threads it returns about 1.4 seconds. This is horrible scaling, it's not even close to cutting the time by 4 and I can't understand why. I appreciate any help.

Comment: A 4x reduction rarely, if ever happens. At best you'll get 3.5x, more likely just 3x. Remember, modern CPUs will often "turbo" one particularly busy core to ludicrous speed, but if more cores are running, they all have to throttle down if there isn't enough thermal headroom.

Comment: What hardware are you running on? If it is a dual-processor with 2 way SMT, then you shouldn't expect 4x speedup anyway. (P.s. It's *much* easier not to force the number of threads, but to use the OMP_NUM_THREADS envirable to set it. )

Comment: Sometimes you can see surprising things, here is what I got on my laptop : `threads= 1, runtime: 1.02207s,
threads= 2, runtime: 0.51268s,
threads= 3, runtime: 0.34443s,
threads= 4, runtime: 0.49750s,
threads= 5, runtime: 0.41232s,
threads= 6, runtime: 0.34729s,
threads= 7, runtime: 0.30273s,
threads= 8, runtime: 0.26884s`

Comment: On the other hand, It scales quite well on a 32 core AMD Epyc server: `1: 1.5067s, 2: 0.7561s, 3: 0.5057s, 4: 0.3797s, 5: 0.3053s, 6: 0.2571s, 7: 0.2209s, 8: 0.1933s, 9: 0.1720s, 10: 0.1560s, 11: 0.1427s, 12: 0.1329s, 13: 0.1218s, 14: 0.1139s, 15: 0.1054s, 16: 0.1006s, 17: 0.0949s, 18: 0.0904s, 19: 0.0847s, 20: 0.0804s, 21: 0.0787s, 22: 0.0762s, 23: 0.0739s, 24: 0.0700s, 25: 0.0838s, 26: 0.0645s, 27: 0.0618s, 28: 0.0609s, 29: 0.0585s, 30: 0.0557s, 31: 0.0545s, 32: 0.0537s,`

Comment: Please specify the *exact processor reference* you are using (eg. i5-9600KF for me). This is critical to understand what is happening. Besides, showing the result of `OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=TRUE` can also help a bit. By the way, please consider tuning the number of thread with `OMP_NUM_THREADS=4` and not using `omp_set_num_threads` hardcoded in your program. Finally, please specify what compiler did you use and the compiler flags (this is important to know the OpenMP runtime implementation and how the code behave).

Comment: You've only given a single data point. Try 2  and 3 threads too. You hardly ever get full speedup to the number of cores. Btw, do you actually have 4 cores?

Comment: yes I do have 4 cores, my proc is an AMD A8-5500B with radeon HD graphics